# Concatenate multiple values of same column with different Ids without Subquery - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

The table is somthing like this

```
   ID | DESC 

   1  | A    
   2  | Ml      
   3  | Liter     
   4  | D    
   5  | E
```

Want to fetch details with given ID (e.g. 1,2,3,4) and display as a string so the Expected Output is
The desired output is something like this
**1 Ml 4 Liter**

I have tried this with SQL-Server.

`(select Id from Table1 Where Id=1) + ' ' + (select DESC from Table1 Where Id=2) + ' ' + (select Id from Table1 Where Id=4) + ' ' + (select DESC from Table1 Where Id=3)`

Is there any different way to fetch this without using the subqueries each time ?

Comment: Q: Why such a perverse set of queries???

Comment: How do you order the rows to get `1 Ml 4 Liter` as a result?

Comment: @Zhorov by passing in the Ids in Order .. like (1,2,4,3) this is with respect to the above table example

Comment: Why "1" and not "A"?

Answer (score 1):

Note that your expected output does not seem to correspond entirely to the data in the `DESC` column.  The `STRING_AGG` function comes to mind here:

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG(DESC, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) AS output
FROM yourTable
WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Something more along the lines of what you are already attempting would be to use conditional aggregation to isolate the various description values:

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN ID = 1 THEN DESC END) + ' ' +
    SUM(CASE WHEN ID = 2 THEN DESC END) + ' ' +
    SUM(CASE WHEN ID = 3 THEN DESC END) + ' ' +
    SUM(CASE WHEN ID = 4 THEN DESC END) AS output
FROM yourTable
WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string_agg()` if your DB version supports it

```
select string_agg(desc,'') from tablename
where id in (1,2,3,4)
```

OR you can use `stuff()`

```
select distinct stuff(( select concat( ' ', desc) from tablename for xml path('')),1,1, '') 
    from tablename id in (1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: I think this won't suffice in this case as the selected column in the given solution is the only 'DESC'.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the following approach may help. The `IDs` and the order of the `IDs` are passed as a table using `VALUES` table value constructor. The example uses `STRING_AGG()` for string aggregation, so you need at least SQL Server 2017. For earlier versions you need to use `FOR XML PATH`:

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (ID int, [DESC] varchar(10))
INSERT INTO Data (ID, [DESC])
VALUES
   ('1', 'A'),
   ('2', 'Ml'),
   ('3', 'Liter'),     
   ('4', 'D'),    
   ('5', 'E')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   STRING_AGG(
      CASE WHEN v.RN % 2 = 1 THEN CONVERT(varchar(10), d.ID) ELSE d.[DESC] END,
      ' '
   ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY v.RN)  
FROM Data d
JOIN (VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 4), (4, 3)) v (RN, ID) ON d.ID = v.ID
```

Result:

```
1 Ml 4 Liter
```